# How to select all in Inbox by Gmail

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I would like to delete all messages with a certain label. In Gmail, I can just click on the label or search for it, click "select all" in top left corner and delete.

How can I do this in Inbox by Gmail? When I open the labelled mails, is there some way to select all, apart from clicking each one separately? I have hundreds of mails to manipulate, so selecting each one by hand is not an option.

Comment: All messages with particular label from inbox not possible i think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to select all messages for a search result or bundle in Inbox by Gmail, but users could use Sweep to mark done emails & reminders.

To do bulk operations, the alternative are, among others, to use:

- Gmail web interface
- IMAP email client
- Google Apps Script

**References**
[How Inbox works with Gmail - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273?hl=en&ref_topic=6067565)
[Mark done emails & reminders - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067561?hl=en)